# ssmpt : how to configure php?

Tags: email, ssmtp

I isntalled successfull ssmtp:

```
/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

root=contact@mydomain.com
www-data=contact@mydomain.com
mailhub=ssl0.ovh.net:587
#mailhub=ns0.ovh.net:587
UseSTARTTLS=YES
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=contact@mydomain.com
AuthPass=********
```

And trying it with:

```
 echo content | mail -s "subject" myemail@gmail.com
```

This works and I do receive email

my ssmpt seems also ok:

```
 ls -la /usr/sbin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Jul 15  2014 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> ssmtp
```

my php.ini has:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

However, when I try to send email through the mail() function: I receive FALSE

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

gives me: **sendmail: Cannot open mailhub:25**

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you submit mail using that particular sendmail command `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ssmtp doesn't support the `-i` argument, and requires `-oi` instead.  Note that `-oi` means the same thing and should work on other sendmail implementations.

Could you try changing your sendmail command to `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -oi`?

ssmtp manpage at: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp.